# Using custom entities in HTML documents

Tags: html, xhtml, localization, html-entities

### tl;dr

I'd like to understand if it is possible (and, in case, how well supported) to use custom entities in HTML documents for localization purposes.

---

What I envision is doing something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html "/locales/en-us.ent">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>&contactus.title;</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>&contactus.youcanreach;<br>123, Example Road<br>12345 Example City</p>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li>&menu.home;</li>
      <li>&menu.products;</li>
      <li>&menu.contactus;</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

and all entities would be stored in a file (one for each language, en-us.ent in the example above) that gets included at the top of the document, e.g.

```
<!ENTITY menu.home "Home">
<!ENTITY menu.products "Products">
<!ENTITY menu.contactus "Contact us">
...
```

Eventually this could even be exapnded to HTML fragments (not sure if this is really allowed) that may be useful on all pages (such as headers, menus, etc.; in the example above, the whole `<ul>` could be such a fragment)

Now, my understanding is that this is theoretically possible in XHTML, but I was wondering if this can be done also in HTML and, in case, how well browsers (and crawlers) would cope.

Comment: Heh! +1 for a cool and original idea, although client support for this would probably be terrible

Comment: @Pekka, I can't really take credit for the idea because it's a mechanism that's extensively used to provide localization support inside Firefox. Still, I think it's an excellent idea that could be profitably used elsewhere.

Comment: It should be easy enough to create a javascript parser which will load a correct translation file and would make "global find-replace". It would be even easier to do that with php or other server-side scripting language. But to make all browser makers to support some rarely used feature is pretty much impossible.

Comment: The idea is theoretically and practically possible in “XHTML”, if that means an XHTML document sent with an XML content type such as application/xhtml+xml, but browsers are not required to process external entity definitions. And search engines most probably don’t interpret entity definitions at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, it is possible. HTML 4.x (and several previous versions) are SGML applications so you can extend the DTD with new entities.

In practise, every mainstream browser implements an HTML specific tag soup slurper instead of a real SGML parser so you can't do this. This is why HTML 4 has a [list of SGML features to avoid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.3) and why HTML 5 isn't an SGML application.