# How To create own Entity Code character in HTML

Tags: html, unicode, character, entity

Is it possible to create custom Entity Code character in HTML ? as if i want to display **space** on web page so i have to Write **&nbsp;** but i want to create custom Entity Code like 
first i set code admin = 'This is admin'
**&admin;** so it should display on page as 'This is admin'.

if it is possible so please help me for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom entities in HTML documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321604/using-custom-entities-in-html-documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi Dear,

I do not know if it is possible or not in HTML.
but you can create in XML.
**Example :**
First You have to write top of XML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE custome_code [
  <!ENTITY admin "This is admin">
]>
```

Now you can use **&admin;** in any where in XML file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, unfortunately, in current browsers (see [Using custom entities in HTML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321604/using-custom-entities-in-html-documents)) - the list of HTML entities is usually fixed. Using a server-side templating language (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.) would allow you to do something similar with variables. E.g. with PHP:

`<?php
     $admin = 'This is admin';
 ?>
 Lorem ipsum <?=$admin?> fillare emptimum spatium.`

Or in javascript / jQuery you could set up placeholders like `<span class="admin"></span>` and then fill them using:

```
$('.admin').html('This is admin');
```

Comment: Is a solution but does not response the original question.